# $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ but it's extension by zero does not belong to $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

My problem is the following: I want to find a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ such that if $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $p\in (1,\infty$), then the extension by zero of $u$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$ is not in $W_0^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

If such $u$ do exist, then the problem must be a problem of "differentiability" in $\partial\Omega$, but I could not figure out how to construct such $u$.

I would like to note that if $\Omega\in C^{0,1}(\Omega)$, then such $u$ does not exist because we have a extension operator between $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such domain. By definition of $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, $u$ is a $W^{1,p}$ limit of smooth compactly supported functions $u_n$.  Extend each $u_n$ by zero; you now have a sequence of smooth compactly supported functions which converges in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$. Its limit is an element of $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb R^N)$, which is nothing else but the zero extension of $u$.

The problem of smoothness of $\partial \Omega$ comes up when you interpret the vanishing of $u$ on the boundary differently, i.e., in the sense of traces. Then the question becomes: does having zero trace imply $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$? If $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz, this is true (e.g., Theorem 15.29 in *A first course in Sobolev spaces* by Leoni). (I see that you know the last part, but it was natural to include it for completeness).

Comment: You are right, I think I made a confusion here. Thank you.

Comment: @user85506 If a function belongs to $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then clearly its zero extension belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$. Why is the converse true?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I saw a proof once but forgot it. Hence, it's an exercise for the reader. (But I will post a proof if I remember).

Comment: @UmbertoP., Brezis gives a proof of it, but he ask some regularity on the boundary: $C^1$.

Comment: Consider the following: let $\Omega$ be the unit ball (in two dimensions) with the segment $[-1/2,1/2]$ deleted from the $x$-axis. Let $f(x) = 1 - |x|^2$.  The zero extension of $f$  belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^2)$ but $f \notin W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Extending this $f$ by $0$ on $\Omega^c$, we get a function that is discontinuous on every line segment crossing $[-1/2,1/2]$. It is not ACL, hence not in $W^{1,p}$. That said, we are getting into the business of representatives, etc... so I think it's best to just delete my unsupported claim. Which I just did.

Comment: Fair enough, but $f$ is in $W^{1,p}$: redefining $f$ on a set of Lebesgue measure zero does not remove it from the Sobolev space.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I think that this result is also valid for $C^{0,1}$ boundarys.